# In Cocos2d-x How to urlencode and decode data coming from webservice

Tags: android, json, httprequest, cocos2d-x, urlencode

I searched for this on google, cocos2d-x wiki, discussion forum and here on stackoverflow as well , but did not got any answer.

I have a web service which gives json string in urlencoded form. How to decode that in cocos2d-x and then convert it into JSON and use it?

I am new to cocos2d-x. Any help will be appretiated.

Comment: I got the answer. There is a library curl. you can use. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html

Answer (score 0):

you can cJSON parser, its good one and easy to use. http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjson/

Comment: Thanks Pratikxman.. Does it have url encode and decode function too. Also, is there any example of using this.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend upon the decoding format. Here is base64 decoding.
Let me know if you need encoding.
To parse Decoding String into Json use rapidjson. It's already in cocos2dx

// Decoding

```
static inline bool is_base64(unsigned char c) {
  return (isalnum(c) || (c == '+') || (c == '/'));
}

string Util::base64_decode(string const& encoded_string) {

      static const std::string base64_chars =
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
      "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      "0123456789+/";

      int in_len = encoded_string.size();
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      int in_ = 0;
      unsigned char char_array_4[4], char_array_3[3];
      std::string ret;

      while (in_len-- && ( encoded_string[in_] != '=') && is_base64(encoded_string[in_])) {
        char_array_4[i++] = encoded_string[in_]; in_++;
        if (i ==4) {
          for (i = 0; i <4; i++)
            char_array_4[i] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[i]);

          char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
          char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
          char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

          for (i = 0; (i < 3); i++)
            ret += char_array_3[i];
          i = 0;
        }
      }

      if (i) {
        for (j = i; j <4; j++)
          char_array_4[j] = 0;

        for (j = 0; j <4; j++)
          char_array_4[j] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[j]);

        char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
        char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
        char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

        for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); j++) ret += char_array_3[j];
      }

      return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Will this work like escape or unescape in javascript. I am receiving data from webservice which is using UrlEncode method in c#.